# Lluís Puig notes in Frobenius systems.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, finite-groups

I have been reading some articles that makes mention about certain investigator called Lluís Puig and his theorems and some notes made by him about Frobenius Systems, but in the references of each writer that says something about him they put "L. Puig, Unpublished Notes". I think that are some notes made in a class that he gave, so I want to ask if someone has a copy of this notes, because can help me about something I'm writting. The only thing that I found about him is his book "Frobenius Categories versus Brauer Blocks: The Grothendieck Group of the Frobenius Category of a Brauer Block", but it doesn't look like that notes. Thanks if someone can help me.

**Edit**

The article that I make mention is *The homotopy of fusion systems* that is from Carles Broto, Ran Levi and Oliver Bob, so the notes that I make mention may be older than 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unpublished notes of Lluís Puig were made in 1992-1993. Puig replaced them by publishing the article

`Frobenius categories`

in the Journal of Algebra 303(2006), 309-357, and his book

`Frobenius Categories versus Brauer Blocks (Progress in Mathematics 274, Birkhäuser, 2009).`

He calls  `Frobenius P-categorias`, what many people has passed to call  `Saturated Fusion Systems`.